# retrieve UITextField using tag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        cell.tag = 0;
    else {
        cell.tag = 1;
    }

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *startDtLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 25)];
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
            startDtLbl.text = @"Username";
        else {
            startDtLbl.text = @"Password";
        }

        startDtLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:startDtLbl];

        UITextField *passwordTF = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 200, 35)];
        passwordTF.delegate = self;
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
            passwordTF.tag = 2;
        else {
            passwordTF.tag = 3;
        }
        [cell.contentView addSubview:passwordTF];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I'd like to get the UITextField, how can I do that? I've tried the following and it failed:

```
UITableViewCell * username_cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.view viewWithTag:0];
    UITableViewCell * password_cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

    UITextField * username = (UITextField*)[username_cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    UITextField * password = (UITextField*)[password_cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    NSLog(@"Username is %@", [username text]);
    NSLog(@"Password is %@", [password text]);
```

Comment: could you explain the table structure? how many rows/sections and what do they contain?

Comment: NEVER EVER you should use tag 0. All views that don't have tags have a tag of 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should stop to use tags to get cells. You should use indexPaths for this.

replace

```
UITableViewCell * username_cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.view viewWithTag:0];
UITableViewCell * password_cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

with

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathUserName = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell * username_cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathUserName];
NSIndexPath *indexPathPassword = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell * password_cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathPassword];
```

---

and when you want to reference a specific view you can't use tag 0. Because all tags that don't have custom tags have a tag of 0. So if you use viewWithTag:0 you get the last added view. And usually that isn't the view you want.

Answer (score 2):

If your textfields are inside uiscrollview and incrementing dynamically

```
int i=0;
    for (UIView *subview in ContentScroll.subviews) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[ subview viewWithTag:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
        NSString *fieldValue = textField.text;
        if ([fieldValue isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            NSLog(@"as");     
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Field %d has value: %@", i, fieldValue);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've answered your question here [login using UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063061/login-using-uitableview/5063424#5063424)

Answer (score 1):

The table appears to only present username and password so I would suggest keeping two pointers to the text fields that get created. This would eliminate the need for tags. The code for tagging the cells could be eliminated and the code that was tagging the text fields could be updated to store a pointer in the view's controller.

```
    UITextField *passwordTF = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 200, 35)];
    passwordTF.delegate = self;
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        self.passwordTextField = passwordTF;
    else {
        self.usernameTextField = passwordTF;
    }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:passwordTF];
```

Comment: and how would you get that UITextField?

Comment: Those textfields would be properties on your view controller. You would replace the calls searching with viewWithTag with just a reference to the property.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is on the on the first lin of this code:

Instead of this:

```
UITableViewCell * username_cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.view viewWithTag:0];
UITableViewCell * password_cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Use this:

```
UITableViewCell * username_cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.tableView viewWithTag:0];
UITableViewCell * password_cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.tableView viewWithTag:1];
```

Or whatever is the name of your tableview. Your are trying to get the UITableViewCells from `self.view`, but UITableViewCells are the subviews of tableview.

**Alternative**

If this doesnot works, then you can find the UITablViewCells, using

```
NSArray *arrTableViewCells = [tableView subviews];
```

and then get the UITextFields from these cells.

It should work